# Display a title only once in a foreach loop

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I tried this but think I'm missing something.
What's wrong with this code? I can't figure it out. Would anyone be able to Help?
I just want to display (annual/monthly membership) category title only once but this displays in every option, please see my screenshot. I understand that this is mainly because of the for each loop but when I move it up and try, it redirect me to homepage. May be I didn't write it properly. Any help is appreciated.

This display category title in every option, which is not what I want.
[image]

```html
<?php
/**
 * @package        Joomla
 * @subpackage     Membership Pro
 * @author         Tuan Pham Ngoc
 * @copyright      Copyright (C) 2012 - 2016 Ossolution Team
 * @license        GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
 */
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<ul class="osm-upgrade-options">
    <?php
    $upgradeOptionCount = 0;
    $display_title = true;
    foreach ($this->upgradeRules as $rule)
    {
        $checked = '';
        if ($upgradeOptionCount == 0)
        {
            $checked = ' checked="checked" ';
        }

        $upgradeOptionCount++;
        $upgradeToPlan = $this->plans[$rule->to_plan_id];
        $symbol = $upgradeToPlan->currency_symbol ? $upgradeToPlan->currency_symbol : $upgradeToPlan->currency;

        $taxRate = 0;
        if ($this->config->show_price_including_tax)
        {
            $taxRate = OSMembershipHelper::calculateMaxTaxRate($rule->to_plan_id);
        }
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('a.title')
        ->from('#__osmembership_categories AS a')
        ->innerJoin('#__osmembership_plans AS b ON a.id = b.category_id')
        ->where('b.id = ' . $rule->to_plan_id);
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $categoryTitle = $db->loadResult();

        if ($categoryTitle == "Annual Membership Plan" && $display_title) {
            echo 'Annual Membership'; 
            $display_title=false;           
        }
        
        else {
            echo 'Monthly Membership';
        }

        ?> 
        <li class="osm-upgrade-option">
            <input type="radio" class="validate[required]" id="upgrade_option_id_<?php echo $upgradeOptionCount; ?>" name="upgrade_option_id" value="<?php echo $rule->id; ?>"<?php echo $checked; ?> />
            <label for="upgrade_option_id_<?php echo $upgradeOptionCount; ?>"><?php JText::printf('OSM_UPGRADE_OPTION_TEXT', $this->plans[$rule->from_plan_id]->title, $upgradeToPlan->title, OSMembershipHelper::formatCurrency($rule->price * (1 + $taxRate / 100), $this->config, $symbol)); ?></label>
        </li>
        <?php
    }


    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using flag variable(if your data is in foreach loop)

```
    <?php
/**
 * @package        Joomla
 * @subpackage     Membership Pro
 * @author         Tuan Pham Ngoc
 * @copyright      Copyright (C) 2012 - 2016 Ossolution Team
 * @license        GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
 */
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<ul class="osm-upgrade-options">
    <?php
    $upgradeOptionCount = 0;
    $display_annual = true;
    $display_month = true;

    foreach ($this->upgradeRules as $rule)
    {
        $checked = '';
        if ($upgradeOptionCount == 0)
        {
            $checked = ' checked="checked" ';
        }

        $upgradeOptionCount++;
        $upgradeToPlan = $this->plans[$rule->to_plan_id];
        $symbol = $upgradeToPlan->currency_symbol ? $upgradeToPlan->currency_symbol : $upgradeToPlan->currency;

        $taxRate = 0;
        if ($this->config->show_price_including_tax)
        {
            $taxRate = OSMembershipHelper::calculateMaxTaxRate($rule->to_plan_id);
        }
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('a.title')
        ->from('#__osmembership_categories AS a')
        ->innerJoin('#__osmembership_plans AS b ON a.id = b.category_id')
        ->where('b.id = ' . $rule->to_plan_id);
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $categoryTitle = $db->loadResult();

        if ($categoryTitle == "Annual Membership Plan") {
            if($display_annual)
            {
                echo 'Annual Membership';     
                $display_annual=false;
            }
        }

        else{
            if($display_month)
            {
                echo 'Monthly Membership';
                $display_month=false;
            }
        }

        ?> 
        <li class="osm-upgrade-option">
            <input type="radio" class="validate[required]" id="upgrade_option_id_<?php echo $upgradeOptionCount; ?>" name="upgrade_option_id" value="<?php echo $rule->id; ?>"<?php echo $checked; ?> />
            <label for="upgrade_option_id_<?php echo $upgradeOptionCount; ?>"><?php JText::printf('OSM_UPGRADE_OPTION_TEXT', $this->plans[$rule->from_plan_id]->title, $upgradeToPlan->title, OSMembershipHelper::formatCurrency($rule->price * (1 + $taxRate / 100), $this->config, $symbol)); ?></label>
        </li>
        <?php
    }


    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @B. Desai But how can I add the else statement. I tried but when added it keeps displaying multiple times.

Comment: @Dilum Jayawardhana update your code so I can get what exactly you need

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work. It didn't display else statement.

Screenshot: http://joxi.ru/12M4zbatEDBMmJ

Comment: I used the else if statement and did something like this: `  elseif ($categoryTitle == "Monthly Membership Plan" && $display_title2){ echo '<div class="monthly-plan">Monthly Membership</div>'; $display_title2=false; } `

Seems like this works..

Comment: It didn't work with variable set to false, so I had to set the variable to true. $display_month = true; Anyway Thanks for helping me. Final out come with some styling. Screenshot: http://joxi.ru/ZrJ4zbLtGELN2j